# Characterize sequence of $n$ such that $x^{x}\equiv (x+1)^{x+1}\pmod n$ for some $x\in\Bbb{Z}, 1\le{x}\lt{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

The first few entries in the sequence are,

3, 11, 13, 19, 23, 29, 31, 43, 49, 53, 57, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 77, 79, 83, 85, 89, 91, 93, 97, 101, 103, ...

Where,

$3$ is an entry since $1^{1}\equiv 2^{2}\pmod 3$.

$11$ is an entry since $8^{8}\equiv 9^{9}\pmod {11}$.

And so on. I looked this sequence up on OEIS and couldn't find anything (so I submitted it to be added). I'm hoping someone
**1.)** might know a related well-known sequence or
**2.)** can find any insightful/useful characterizations of this sequence.

Comment: Factors of $(x+1)^{x+1} - x^x$ greater than $x$. e.g. since $5^5-4^4 = 2869 = 19 \times 151$, each of $19, 151, 2869$ are in the sequence.

Comment: The limitation $x<n$ is rather arbitrary and unnatural. Without it, the sequence would surely look nicer.